# python for loop with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, nested-for-loop

This is my data set:

```
    q1  q2  q3     q4
0   a   a   a   a
1   b   a   a   a
2   c   c   b   a
3   d   d   b   a
4   a   a   a   a
5   b   c   b   a
6   b   a   b   a
7   c   c   b   a
8   d   d   b   a
```

where column

- q1 has 'a','b','c','d' column values.
- q2 has 'a','c','d' column values.
- q3 has 'a','b' column values.
- q4 has 'a' column values.

I want to run a for-loop for all columns with the common equation, but all the columns do not have all values. I am getting an error.

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8RwN.png)

```
col = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']

for i in col:
    print((df[i].value_counts()['a']) + (df[i].value_counts()['b']) + (df[i].value_counts()['c']) + (df[i].value_counts()['d']))
```

Comment: can you add the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with multiple if conditions to check the value in the particular column:

```
col = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']

for i in col:
    count = 0
    if 'a' in df[i].unique():
        count += df[i].value_counts()['a']
    if 'b' in df[i].unique():
        count += df[i].value_counts()['b']
    if 'c' in df[i].unique():
        count += df[i].value_counts()['c']
    if 'd' in df[i].unique():
        count += df[i].value_counts()['d']
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by declaring the values in your for():

```
col = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']
values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in col:
    count = 0
    for v in values:
        if v in df[i].values:
            count += df[i].value_counts()[v]
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use, create list and append:

```
list_C = []
for i in cols:
    a = df[i].str.count("A").sum()
    list_C.append(a)
    b = df[i].str.count("B").sum()
    list_C.append(b)
    c = df[i].str.count("C").sum()
    list_C.append(c)
    d = df[i].str.count("D").sum()
    list_C.append(d)

print(list_C)
print(sum(list_C))
```